# creating a deskband (WMP style taskbar toolbar) in vb net

Tags: vb.net, taskbar, windows-media-player

I have searched and searched how to do this but everything leads back to Appbars (dockable forms) which is not what i need.

I want a toolbar that goes into the taskbar, like WMP, itunes, language toolbar.

Preferably in vbnet, but if its in C# then thats fine.

Comment: FYI, these have been removed from Windows 7.

Comment: so there is no way to make an itunes/wmp type toolbar because I have both of those on my win 7. That's quite annoying but I think I can get around it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found this on the codeproject. It is in C#, but you could always make it Vb.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/dotnetbandobjects.aspx

Answer (score 1):

**You should not be writing shell extensions in a managed language at all**, even if some online examples show how to do it. Mainly because only one CLR can be loaded per process. So once your extension is loaded into `explorer.exe`, anybody else's extension specifying a different .net version won't load. And vice versa, of course, if your extension is not the first one to load.

See [Raymond Chen's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/12/18/1317290.aspx) for more info.